# Prefer function-pointer or function-object when customizing sort and map?

Tags: c++, templates, compare, function-pointers, function-object

I want to customizing sort template and map template in C++

Here are for comparing,

```
struct Greater1
{
    bool operator() (string A, string B)
    {
        string AB = A + B;
        string BA = B + A;
        return (AB >BA);
    }
};

static bool Greater2(string A, string B)
{
    string AB = A + B;
    string BA = B + A;
    return (AB >BA);
}
```

After my test Greater1 works for map and Greater2 works for sort. I also got some information form CPLUSPLUS and found that both and map should use both  of function pointer and function object. 
My question is why Greater2 could work for map and Greater1 could work for sort.

Comment: Depending on your use, both should work equally well for any purpose. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us how you use the structure and function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: If I recall, functionoid-objects can have performance/size differences, that _may_ have an effect.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I could not even compile following code successfully, sort(str.begin(), str.end(), Greater1);  or map<string, int, Greater2> minmap;

Comment: You may prefer a function object instead of a function pointer because the former can be inlined. This may make a difference, and it does e.g. in `std::sort` vs the C-style version `qsort`

Comment: Then edit your question to include the code that causes the error(s) ***and*** the actual errors (complete and unmodified).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For interchanging function object and pointer with `std::map` you need to specify type for function pointer, like following

```
typedef std::function< bool(string,string)> compare;
```

Then,

```
std::map<string, string, compare >  m(Greater2) ;
```

For `std::sort`

```
sort(beginIt, endIt, Greater1() ); // since Greater1 is type
```

or

```
sort(beginIt, endIt, Greater2 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just one more question, why map needs to know the type of function pointer, whereas sort does not?  why sort needs to know type of function object(why needs "()"), whereas map does not?  Thank you so very much!!

Answer (score 3):

[`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) takes an instance of a [`Compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) object, while the class template [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) allows you to specify the type of the `Compare`. You likely tried to use `Greater1`, a type, like this:

```
sort(beginIt, endIt, Greater1);
```

which is incorrect. You should use it as

```
sort(beginIt, endIt, Greater1());
```

However, since `Greater2` is a function pointer and not a type name,

```
sort(beginIt, endIt, Greater2);
```

works fine.

With an `std::map`, you need to provide a type. So, you would need to use something like `Greater1`. You could also use the [std::map constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map) that allows you to specify the `Compare` object and some template magic to end up using `Greater2` like this:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename Compare>
std::map<Key, Value, Compare> make_map(Compare const& comp)
{
 return std::map<Key, Value, Compare>(comp);
}
```

And you can now make a map like this:

```
auto myMap = make_map<std::string, std::string>(Greater2);
```

Comment: The type *may* not be needed for the `std::map`, if the comparator function is passed to the [`std::map` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Which is tricky to do without writing a type: `std::map<string, string, ???>(Greater1{});`  Not impossible definitely, but tricky.

Comment: @MooingDuck Note that I say *may* :) For the function, if the arguments match standard type used for the map, then you don't need the type

Comment: @Pradhan You can use `std::function` as I've in my answer

Comment: @P0W Ah right. That is probably better than my convoluted `make_map` :)